# Use the same WPF window for two different purposes

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a WPF application  written in VB with several windows. These windows have a several controls in them for the users to enter data. This data is then saved to a database. I want the users to be a able to edit a given set of data and it would be a lot more convenient to use the same window the data was entered in. Depending on whether the user clicks "Add" or "Edit", I want to run different code behind the window.

My issue is that I can't figure out how to differentiate between these two events. The MainWindow class has buttons "Add" and "Edit". When clicked, they create a new tab that contains a new instance of "Data.xaml". "Data.xaml" has "Data.vb" behind it. How can "Data.vb" tell whether it should execute "Edit" or "Add" code?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to add some property to the `Data` class which will tell what should be done:

```
Public Partial Class Data Inherits Window
    // ...

    Public Property Mode As Mode

    // ...
End Class
```

where `Mode` is enum with two fields: `Add` and `Edit`.

In click handler of `Add` button set `Mode` to `Mode.Add`, in click handler of `Edit` button set `Mode` to `Mode.Edit`.

If you want to prevent changing of `Mode` after window constructed you can create new constructor that will take mode as an argument:

```
Public Partial Class Data Inherits Window
    // ...

    Public Sub New(mode As Mode)
        Me.New()
        Mode = mode
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Mode As Mode

    // ...
End Class
```

Then in your logic in `Data.vb` look at the `Mode` and do appropriate actions.

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim dataWindow = New Data(Mode.Add)
    dataWindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub EditButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim dataWindow = New Data(Mode.Edit)
    dataWindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI question is VB, so it might be nice to translate your code accordingly.

Comment: @Craig Thank you. I didn't notice `vb.net` tag.

Comment: I should have been more clear - `Data` is a class contained in a frame which in turn is contained in a tabitem. My problem is passing information through frame...